# $\partial (A \cap B) = \partial A \cap \partial B $?

Tags: general-topology

let $A,B$ be subsets of topological space $X$. Does it follow

$\partial (A \cap B) = \partial A \cap \partial B $ ?

Comment: Try to find counterexamples for both inclusions.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

On these types of problems it's always best to draw picture when there's an opportunity to!

[image]

Comment: ms paint XD ///

Comment: @user153330 yes, ms paint, I would use Paint 3D that comes with windows nowadays.

Answer (score 3):

Let $X = \mathbb{R}$, $A = \mathbb{Q}$, and $B = \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$ be the rationals and irrationals.  What do you get?

Answer (score 3):

Consider $X=\mathbb{R}$, with the usual topology.  If $A=[-1,1]$ and $B=[-2,2]$, then $\partial(A\cap B)=\partial([-1,1])=\{-1,1\}$; $\partial A=\{-1,1\}$; and $\partial B=\{-2,2\}$.

But certainly, $\{-1,1\}\neq \{-1,1\}\cap\{-2,2\}$.